# gettransaction cannot get address where it send from

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

Hi i have test few time with gettransaction method, it seem only show full detail about transaction when send inside node.

But if i send from another address outside my node, gettransaction only show transaction detail of receive address.

How i can get full detail for both ways even that address not come from my node

Comment: Can you provide example transactions and the outputs?

Comment: it should display like this : https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d15e70e603bc4b628681ec9fff2362dd  but when i receive it only display detail about category receive, detail array only contain category receive, send category not appear, and look like this : https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e66e2773205040e6aa8d30c2e94ba62a

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is a byproduct of the now-deprecated account system. The send/receive labels are applied according to the addresses that are part of your wallet.

If you want the sender/recipient details as a whole, pass the raw tx hex to `decoderawtransaction`. This will give you the inputs and outputs as they appear in the transaction, without the accounting filters on it.

Comment: i already track in getrawtransaction, but it seem i dont see any sender address here.

Comment: That's because Bitcoin transactions don't have a "sender" address. Gettransaction shows you the effect on your wallet (address incoming funds were received with, address outgoing funds are sent to).